# Electrolysis of copper sulphate solution using platinum electrode

Tags: electricity

Please explain the electrolysis of copper sulphate solution using platinum electrodes ,and explain why copper ion was preferencially discharged rather than hydrogen ion,and also were the hydrogen came from

Answer (score 1):

At the cathode the reaction is:

$$ ne + X^{n+} \rightarrow X $$

where $X^{n+}$ could be $Cu^{2+}$ or $H^+$. The $Cu^{2+}$ comes from the copper sulphate dissolved in the water and the $H^+$ comes from the dissociation of the water:

$$ H_2O \rightarrow H^+ + OH^{-} $$

The equilibrium constant for the above reaction is $10^{-14}$ for pure water at room temperature so the concentration of $H^+$ is $10^{-7}$ moles per litre. The presence of copper actually shifts the equilibrium slightly because copper binds the hydroxide ion, but let's ignore that for now.

The question is why copper is produced at the cathode rather than hydrogen, and the answer is simply that hydrogen reduces the copper ion. So if electrons react with hydrogen ions in the water we get a chain of two reactions:

$$\begin{align}
e + H^{+} &\rightarrow H \\
2H + Cu^{2+} &\rightarrow 2H^+ + Cu
\end{align}$$

So whether the electron reacts with the hydrogen or copper ions the result is always to produce metallic copper.

Comment: You might consider reading about the electrochemical series which is page two of this article? http://www.chemguide.co.uk/physical/redoxeqia/introduction.html#top